# Unable to read file from the Downloads folder for an android app

Tags: android, file-io, inputstream

I want to create an inputstream for a file that is stored in the Downloads folder of my phone.
Earlier I had the required file as an asset and I read it with this code:

```
InputStream fin;
fin = getAssets().open(FILENAME);
```

However now I want to be able to open a file stored in my downloads folder `/mnt/sdcard/Download` as an InputStream **NOT** as a FileInputStream Object. I am using a library which requires an InputStream only as an argument so I can not use the FileInputStream
methods because I get a `fatal exception` if I do and the App stops.

How do I go about this? I tried to find some helper function from the documentation, but could not.

Edit: I also tried editing the code to this-

```
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/Download"+FILENAME;
fin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
```

However still when I try to read the file, the App crashes.

Comment: Try with this one: `AssetManager am = context.getAssets();` and
`InputStream fin = am.open(FILENAME);` Or you can also try like that: `InputStream fin = openFileInput(FILENAME);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @g00dy. But I think the function `openFileInput`  returns a `FileInputStream` and not an `InputStream` which I want. Also I would appreciate if you elaborate a little bit on your first solution.

Comment: Looks like you are new to Java an Object-Orientation. Every FileInputStream is a InputStream because it is a super class of FileInputStream. Select FileInputStream text in Eclipse and press F4. Then you can see the structure yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as yours :

```
AssetManager am=getAssets();
InputStream is=am.open("file1.xls");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filepath);
Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(is);
```

Here I used to access file1.xls from the assets folder.

I fixed it by using :

```
File filepath = newFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/"+"file1.xls");  // fist part gets the directory of download folder and last part is your file name
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filepath);
Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(is);
```

Don't forget to get the storage permission first to access the storage.